# adal.js doesn't refresh token properly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, adal, adal.js

I'm working on a Vue.js SPA. The site is running on one host, web.xxxx.com, while the api is running on another, api.xxxx.com. API calls are secured, and we use ADAL to login, logout, and to provide the logged in user's token to the API. In Vue, we set up an interceptor as follows (`getToken` is a wrapper around `acquireToken` that returns a promise):

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {
  // if this is a call to API, then set up auth
  Vue.http.options.xhr = {withCredentials: true};
  getToken()
    .then((token) => {
      request.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
      next();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      throw new Error(err);
    });
});
```

This works as expected; whenever an HTTP request is initiated, the interceptor sets additional headers and off it goes.

However, adal.js isn't updating the tokens. After an hour, my logged in user is not longer logged in, despite interacting with the API. I've even tried running this, to ensure the token isn't being refreshed:

```
// ping every minute...
window.setInterval(() => {
  getToken().then((token) => { window.Logging.log('GOT IT!!!', token); });
}, 60 * 1000);
```

After 55 minutes, these entries appear in the client logs. I redacted anything that may be sensitive, and it should be noted that this takes so long because I was manually stepping through all the calls in the debugger:

```
Fri, 21 Apr 2017 22:11:32 GMT:1.0.14-VERBOSE: renewing idtoken
Fri, 21 Apr 2017 22:11:45 GMT:1.0.14-INFO: renewIdToken is called
Fri, 21 Apr 2017 22:12:08 GMT:1.0.14-INFO: Add adal frame to document:adalIdTokenFrame
Fri, 21 Apr 2017 22:13:26 GMT:1.0.14-VERBOSE: Renew Idtoken Expected state: <REDACTED>
Fri, 21 Apr 2017 22:13:36 GMT:1.0.14-INFO: Navigate url:https://login.microsoftonline.com/<REDACTED>&x-client-SKU=Js&x-client-Ver=1.0.14
Fri, 21 Apr 2017 22:14:06 GMT:1.0.14-VERBOSE: Navigate to:https://login.microsoftonline.com/<REDACTED>
Fri, 21 Apr 2017 22:14:14 GMT:1.0.14-VERBOSE: Set loading state to pending for: <REDACTED>
Fri, 21 Apr 2017 22:14:14 GMT:1.0.14-INFO: LoadFrame: adalIdTokenFrame
Fri, 21 Apr 2017 22:14:53 GMT:1.0.14-INFO: Add adal frame to document:adalIdTokenFrame
Fri, 21 Apr 2017 22:15:01 GMT:1.0.14-INFO: LoadFrame: adalIdTokenFrame
Fri, 21 Apr 2017 22:15:06 GMT:1.0.14-INFO: Add adal frame to document:adalIdTokenFrame
2017-04-21 18:15:07.866 vue.common.js:6183 You are running Vue in development mode.
Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production.
See more tips at https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html
Fri, 21 Apr 2017 22:15:10 GMT:1.0.14-VERBOSE: State: <REDACTED>
Fri, 21 Apr 2017 22:15:10 GMT:1.0.14-INFO: Returned from redirect url
Fri, 21 Apr 2017 22:15:10 GMT:1.0.14-INFO: State status:false; Request type:UNKNOWN
Fri, 21 Apr 2017 22:15:10 GMT:1.0.14-INFO: Error :login_required; Error description:AADSTS50058: A silent sign-in request was sent but no user is signed in. The cookies used to represent the user's session were not sent in the request to Azure AD. This can happen if the user is using Internet Explorer or Edge, and the web app sending the silent sign-in request is in different IE security zone than the Azure AD endpoint (login.microsoftonline.com).
Trace ID: <REDACTED>
Correlation ID: <REDACTED>
Timestamp: 2017-04-21 22:15:01Z
```

Thanks very much for your ongoing help with this, it's much appreciated.

EDITED... added the log output.

Comment: It seems  adal tries to renew the token but it fails since the AAD authentication cookie is expired or not presen . You could use acquireTokenFailure event to capture the "login_required" error and redirect the user to login page

Comment: Yeah, but this doesn't solve the problem that the user will be logged out after an hour long session. I don't want them to get logged out after an hour if they're interacting with the application, so how do I keep their token refreshed?

Comment: If  the session is gone (user signed out) then we will not be able to extend the session further without user interaction.

Comment: Why would the session be gone if I'm calling `acquireToken` once every minute? At some point `acquireToken` tries to renew the token, but for some reason isn't able to successfully complete this action. See the `window.setInterval` code above...